# Why does my iPhone 4 get so hot during charging?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 4 gets hot as the battery is charged. To compound the issue, I think I bought a cheap case that traps heat, which in turn makes the phone even hotter -- you can feel the heat if you hold it in your hand while it is charging. When you stop charging it, the excess heat goes away.

My question is: does this damage the hardware? Also, to reduce the heat, I put the phone on the floor (which is cooler) and I found that the device was not as hot as before (previously I had put the phone to charge on a wooden table). I am unsure as to whether my measure helps in elongating the battery life and protecting the electronic components.

Comment: Up to what temperature does the iPhone get?

Comment: Same with my iphone 5..I think you will need to change the battery for the phone or just go to a phone store and explain to them maybe they will help you :) GOOD LUCK

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FYI, iPhone 4 does have heat sensors and if it gets dangerously hot it will show a black screen with a yellow warning sign and shut down. It's perfectly reasonable to be concerned and take the measures you have to increase heat dissipation, but batteries warming on charging is quite normal. I wouldn't worry unless the iPhone displays an overheating warning consistently.

Answer (score 2):

The charging process heats the device (phone/laptop/or any other battery), make sure that it’s relatively acceptable. If in doubt take it to an Apple Store together with your charger to compare with others. If you live in a very hot place, it might be safer to help dissipate heat by using the floor or any other metal surface.

If it gets too hot, the battery will not be happy and will “last less”.